# iPXE boot over Wireless Network

Tags: wifi, ipxe

I am looking for a way to clone a stack of laptops who do not have an ethernet-port.

I have a Clonezilla-server up and running, where i can clone to other laptops over TFTP or HTTP.

iPXE.org claims to have a wireless solution to go over HTTP. To Date i have not found a way to make this work. If i go the iPXE (wired) to HTTP route i get no problems.

Anyone has alot of experience with iPXE wireless?

To start i dont think iPXE has support for the wireless drivers in the laptops i am trying this on, but i could find no information over this on ipxe.org.

P.S. i know i probably have left alot of info out of the question that will prove necessary in the future, but i have no idea how to start this question any more decent, so forgive me for that. I will try to update the question as frequent as i can.

Answer (score 4):

Since none replied i thought i share the solution i found with you guys.
This is a snippit from a decent guide i found on coreboot.org

Building
Identify your wireless network card:

`# lspci
03:06.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR922X Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`

Identify its PCI IDs:

`# lspci -s 03:06.0 -nnn
03:06.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR922X Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0029] (rev 01)`

Get iPXE:

`git clone git://git.ipxe.org/ipxe.git
cd ipxe/src/`

Copy the following into config/local/general.h:

`#undef PXE_STACK               /* PXE stack in iPXE - you want this! */`

`#undef PXE_MENU                /* PXE menu booting */`

`#undef DOWNLOAD_PROTO_TFTP     /* Trivial File Transfer Protocol */`

`#undef SANBOOT_PROTO_ISCSI     /* iSCSI protocol */`

`#undef SANBOOT_PROTO_AOE       /* AoE protocol */`

`#undef SANBOOT_PROTO_IB_SRP    /* Infiniband SCSI RDMA protocol */`

`#undef SANBOOT_PROTO_FCP       /* Fibre Channel protocol */`

`#undef CRYPTO_80211_WEP        /* WEP encryption (deprecated and insecure!) */`

`#undef CRYPTO_80211_WPA        /* WPA Personal, authenticating with passphrase */`

`#undef CRYPTO_80211_WPA2       /* Add support for stronger WPA cryptography */`

`#undef IMAGE_NBI               /* NBI image support */`

`#undef IMAGE_ELF               /* ELF image support */`

`#undef IMAGE_MULTIBOOT         /* MultiBoot image support */`

`#undef IMAGE_PXE               /* PXE image support */`

`#define        IMAGE_SCRIPT            /* iPXE script image support */`

`#define        IMAGE_BZIMAGE           /* Linux bzImage image support */`

`#undef IMAGE_COMBOOT           /* SYSLINUX COMBOOT image support */`

`#undef IMAGE_EFI               /* EFI image support */`

`#undef IMAGE_SDI               /* SDI image support */`

`#undef NVO_CMD                 /* Non-volatile option storage commands */`

`#undef FCMGMT_CMD              /* Fibre Channel management commands */`

`#undef ROUTE_CMD               /* Routing table management commands */`

`#define IMAGE_CMD               /* Image management commands */`

`#undef SANBOOT_CMD             /* SAN boot commands */`

`#undef MENU_CMD                /* Menu commands */`

`#undef LOGIN_CMD               /* Login command */`

`#undef SYNC_CMD                /* Sync command */`

`#undef NSLOOKUP_CMD            /* DNS resolving command */`

`#undef TIME_CMD                /* Time commands */`

`#undef DIGEST_CMD              /* Image crypto digest commands */`

`#undef LOTEST_CMD              /* Loopback testing commands */`

`#undef VLAN_CMD                /* VLAN commands */`

`#undef PXE_CMD         /* PXE commands */`

`#undef REBOOT_CMD             /* Reboot command */`

`#undef IMAGE_TRUST_CMD /* Image trust management commands */`

Copy the following in the shell.ipxe file:

`#!ipxe
shell`

shell.ipxe is an ipxe script that ipxe will run when starting, here it will instruct ipxe to drop directly to a shell. The syntax is documented on ipxe website.

Use the previously gathered PCI ID to include only the ath9k driver:

`make clean; make -j3 bin/168c0029.rom EMBED=./shell.ipxe`

Go into your coreboot directory:

`cd ../../coreboot/`

Add the iPXE option rom:

`./build/cbfstool ./build/coreboot.rom print
./build/cbfstool ./build/coreboot.rom add -f ../ipxe/src/bin/168c0029.rom -n pci168c,0029.rom -t raw
./build/cbfstool ./build/coreboot.rom print`

Booting

boot on ipxe, it will give you a shell:
iPXE>
You will then need to type some commands to make it boot over the WiFi from the Internet.

Identify your ESSID:

`iwlist`

Set the ESSID:

`config`

Get an IP address:

`dhcp`

Test the official demo (requires a PS/2 keyboard)

`chain http://boot.ipxe.org/demo/boot.php`